# How to pass int array between activities?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I wanted to pass high-resolution `drawable ints` between activities and display it on `ImageViews` so I made this void in the first activity **Examples.class**:

```
private void PATHS(int PATH_1, int PATH_2, int PATH_3, int PATH_4, int PATH_5)
{
    int[] xPATHS = {PATH_1,PATH_2, PATH_3, PATH_4, PATH_5};
    Intent intent = new Intent(Examples.this, ExamplesViewer.class);
    intent.putExtra("PATHS", xPATHS);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

And I called it in the list listener:

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                PATHS(R.drawable.imageone, R.drawable.imagetwo, R.drawable.imagethree, R.drawable.imagefour, R.drawable.imagefive);
        }
    });
}}
```

Then I received it in the second activity "ExamplesViewer.class":

```
    Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();
    int[] PATHS = intent.getIntArray("PATHS");
    ImageView xImageView_1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.PATH_1);
    ImageView xImageView_2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.PATH_2);
    ImageView xImageView_3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.PATH_3);
    ImageView xImageView_4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.PATH_4);
    ImageView xImageView_5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.PATH_5);


    final BitmapFactory.Options xbm = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    xbm.inSampleSize = 2;

    DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    Bitmap xImage_1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), PATHS[0], xbm);
    xImageView_1.setImageBitmap(xImage_1);
    xImageView_1.getLayoutParams().height = height;
    xImageView_1.getLayoutParams().width = width;
    Bitmap xImage_2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), PATHS[1], xbm);
    xImageView_2.setImageBitmap(xImage_2);
    xImageView_2.getLayoutParams().height = height;
    xImageView_2.getLayoutParams().width = width;
    Bitmap xImage_3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), PATHS[2], xbm);
    xImageView_3.setImageBitmap(xImage_3);
    xImageView_3.getLayoutParams().height = height;
    xImageView_3.getLayoutParams().width = width;
    Bitmap xImage_4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), PATHS[3], xbm);
    xImageView_4.setImageBitmap(xImage_4);
    xImageView_4.getLayoutParams().height = height;
    xImageView_4.getLayoutParams().width = width;
    Bitmap xImage_5 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), PATHS[4], xbm);
    xImageView_5.setImageBitmap(xImage_5);
    xImageView_5.getLayoutParams().height = height;
    xImageView_5.getLayoutParams().width = width;
```

The thing is when I run this on my emulator it works fine but when I run it on an actual device it takes me to my `MainActivity`

PS: I tried to run it on several devices but still not working.

-----------------**EDIT**-------------

log cat error `Out of memory on a 8294416-byte allocation.`
PLUS IT DOESN'T WORK ON THE EMULATOR ANYMORE.

Comment: Can you post the log cat output?

Comment: @LokiSinclair the log doesn't detect any errors because the code works fine on the emulator.

Comment: @LokiSinclair I updated with the log cat.

Answer (score 3):

While sending Instead of

```
int[] xPATHS = {PATH_1,PATH_2, PATH_3, PATH_4, PATH_5};
Intent intent = new Intent(Examples.this, ExamplesViewer.class);
intent.putExtra("PATHS", xPATHS);
```

try

```
int[] xPATHS = {PATH_1,PATH_2, PATH_3, PATH_4, PATH_5};
Intent intent = new Intent(Examples.this, ExamplesViewer.class);
Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
bundle.putIntArray("PATHS", xPATHS);                                 // Change here
```

Instead of

```
Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();
int[] PATHS = intent.getIntArray("PATHS");
```

try

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
int[] PATHS = bundle.getIntArrayExtra("PATHS");   // change here
```

Comment: No, Bundle doesn't have a method called getIntArrayExtra... I think you meant Intent intent = getIntent(); ... but then that is only a convenience method and calls getIntArray on the extras bundle it contains

Comment: Intent doesn't have a method called putIntArray and Bundle deosn't have a method called getIntArrayExtra?

Comment: @user2989698, my mistake, I have updated the answer, please check it.

Comment: @user3322955 the second activity couldn't find the PATHS array because you didn't do anything with the Bundle...I guess?

Comment: @user2989698 have you check the updation I just did ? I request you to please check it again.

Comment: @user3322955 I just checked it. the method "getIntArrayExtra" doesn't exist I replaced it with "getIntArray" method. But still the same error.